# Gnuplot crashes when called from application

Tags: c++, linux, gnuplot

I'd like to use gnuplot to plot my results in a console application (C++, Eclipse CDT, Linux). I created a simple a class to make things easier (see code below). I try to plot a test plot in my main:

```
int main() {

    Gnuplot plot;

    plot("plot sin(x)") ;

    cout<<"Press button:";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that if I start my application normally I receive a run-time error message that 'Failed to initialize wxWidgets. Segmentation fault (core dumped)' after executing the line plot("plot sin(x)"). However, if I step through the lines in debug mode the code works fine and my plot window shows up as expected with a sine. Any help would be welcome.

```
#ifndef GNUPLOT_H_
#define GNUPLOT_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Gnuplot {

    public:
        Gnuplot() ;
        ~Gnuplot();
        void operator ()(const string & command); // send any command to gnuplot

    protected:
        FILE *gnuplotpipe;
};
#endif
```

and the source:

```
#include "gnuplot.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdio.h"

Gnuplot::Gnuplot() {

    gnuplotpipe=popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
    if (!gnuplotpipe) {
    cerr<< ("Gnuplot not found !");
    }
}

Gnuplot::~Gnuplot() {

    fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"exit\n");
    pclose(gnuplotpipe);
}

void Gnuplot::operator()(const string & command) {

    fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"%s\n",command.c_str());
    fflush(gnuplotpipe);// flush is neccessary, nothing gets plotted else
};
```

Comment: You don't have any WxWidget related code shown. If you use widget code, show it. Also compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and learn to use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: No widget code here and afaik there is no need for that. Gnuplot is installed and can be used via the terminal. I'd like to call gnuplot through the pipe. I'm compiling with -Wall and -g3. Please be more specific on my debugger skills instead of sending me the back of the row.

Comment: Does `echo 'plot sin(x); exit' | gnuplot -persist`  works in a terminal? And you could add some `sleep(1);` just after the `pclose` ...

Comment: It works fine, plots the expected sine in a window. Sleep(1) didn't help (I included unistd.h to compile).

Comment: Perhaps try adding the `sleep(1)` just after the `popen` .... pparently, `gnuplot` is using WxWidgets, and is crashing for you...

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1221300

Comment: Try adding "set terminal png; set output 'graph.png'; " to your commands before the plot command.  Does this work ok? It should send the graph to the file, not the screen, in this case.

Comment: Paul, your tip worked, the png has been created in my debug directory.

Comment: Are you sure to have a `DISPLAY` ?

Comment: @Basile I think thats it.  He needs to know how to get a DISPLAY.

Answer (score 2):

Executing without a link to the X server will cause this problem. Normally ssh does not give you a link to the X server (but can be configured or switched to do so).  I find I can duplicate the error cited by "ssh localhost" and entering gnuplot and a plotting command, it will assume wxt is the terminal type and give the failed to initiaize wxWidgets error and segfault.

I find it will work for me, though, if I do this first.

**Warning: the first command "xhost +" is dangerous, it disables X security and allows anything, anywhere on the internet to connect to your screen, keyboard, or mouse.**  This may be less of a problem if the machine is behind a network-address-translation router, such as those used in home networking.

From shell:

```
xhost +
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Start gnuplot programmatically, then send gnuplot commands as normal.
Should work.  Working for me at the moment in the ssh login.  If it doesn't, check the env you are using to start the new process with and put "DISPLAY=:0.0" in there explicitly.  This means connect to the local display.  A hostname can be added before the :

Under Linux , gnuplot ususally looks for an X server. It may not be finding it.

Perhaps if the goal is to save your graphs in files, then add:

```
set terminal png
set output 'graph.png'
```

to your gnuplot commands before the "plot" command.  This should work even on headless servers.

If you want control over the output filename, just send some other name instead of graph.png

Comment: This is just fine but I need some kind of interactivity (zoom) to verify my calculations and algorithms. So I'd stick to window plots. However, it is good to know that something is wrong at my display side.

Comment: I think I found the full solution and updated my answer.  Basile provided a strong hint with his DISPLAY comment.

Comment: entered xhost + and export DISPLAY=:0.0 into the terminal then started my app by running it in the IDE, unfortunately with the same error message.

Comment: In Linux and most unices, env is a shared string of val;ues (more or less a string based associative array) that gets passed down the process tree.  You need to get DISPLAY=:0.0 into the env.  popen() won't do that.  You need execve possibly; http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

Comment: If you do X over ssh, it's much more secure to use `ssh -X` instead of opening access to your X server to anybody.

Comment: A good IDE might have a way of inspecting env.  You can inspect it from gnuplot using 'system "set"'.  This just runs "set" in a shell, which prints the env. However, even this could mislead, because we don't know how much of env is passed from gnuplot to the shell it spawns, since it is possible to change what the child inherits in its env.

Comment: @Paul: execve? oooh. I just wanted to use gnuplot from a simple c++ console application. I'm slightly confused now. Maybe I should pick a different plot library.

Comment: @liori That's true.  He is trying to debug a program whose problem is incorrect setting to access the X server and lack of access to the X server.  The use of ssh here is simply to recreate a misconfigured environment. I'm not suggesting he use ssh this way normally.

Comment: @JustGreg Can you start your IDE from the terminal window, specifically the one you enter the commands  xhost + and export DISPLAY=:0.0 into?  This will put the display value into the IDE's environment and it might get passed down when you run the code for testing.  If you use a new terminal window, you have to do the commands over again.  Starting the IDE by clicking on a menu or icon will not copy the env containing DISPLAY=:0.0 entered in the terminal because the env is copied parent process to child process.

Comment: popen() is equivalent to a fork() and some version of exec in one of the forks.  The latter route lets you change more stuff when you create the child process.  There are often helper libraries that people write because it can get hairy.

Comment: @JustGreg There should be a gnuplot C++ library already.  This is surely a solved problem.  It is just a question of whether anyone was nice enough to share their code.  I should note that in perl or python this would be a "use free code written already" problem.

Comment: @Paul: opened up a terminal window, entered xhost +, then export DISPLAY=:0.0 then entered eclipse which started my IDE. Running my app gave the same erroneous results, unfortunately. I really appreciate your efforts, by the way.

Comment: @Paul: I actually have bumped into a thin interface called gnuplot_i. However, I was not able to use that from my IDE, it was probably my fault. I couldn't link my project against gnuplot_i.o.

Answer (score 1):

The following code (in C, not C++) works fine for me (when started from a terminal inside some X11 session, so `DISPLAY` is set to `:0.0`) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  FILE *gp = NULL;
  if (!getenv("DISPLAY")) 
    {fprintf(stderr, "no display\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
  gp = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
  if (!gp) {perror("gnuplot popen"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
  //sleep (1);
  fprintf(gp, "plot sin(x)\n");
  fflush(gp);
  fprintf(gp, "exit\n");
  fflush(gp);
  //sleep (1);
  pclose (gp);
  return 0;
}
```

<sup>(working on Debian/Sid x86-64 with gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0)</sup>

I guess that `sleep`-ing is practically useful to let `gnuplot` get enough time to work. And don't forget to `fflush` after every command.

### addenda:

You should have a `DISPLAY`. If you got the `no display` error message, then that means that you are starting your program in the wrong environment. No programming tricks can help in that case, since `gnuplot` needs some [X11 server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) to talk with.

So you should explain much more how you are starting your application. I guess that it happens to work from Eclipse simply because Eclipse runs with some X11 server, while without Eclipse you happen to not have any X11 server available. (I cannot explain why, it depends so much of the way you start your program. If ussing `ssh` don't forget to `ssh -X` and configure your *ssh* appropriately).

In fact my calls to `sleep` are useless. But testing the existence of a `DISPLAY` is essential.

<sup>It is actually some bug in `gnuplot` which should fail more nicely without a `DISPLAY`; I added a ticket on their bug tracker. You can reproduce the bug with `unset DISPLAY; echo 'plot sin(x); exit' | gnuplot -persist`</sup>

Comment: Does it duplicate the wxwidget error message if the sleep/flush is left off?

Comment: I'll check it in a minute.

Comment: I suspect gnuplot is confused selecting or finding the graphics driver.  That's what the other stuff I read centers around.  It may be getting better config information for X when run as a child of the shell than when run as a child from custom C++ code, possibly. Another possibility was other code needing updates; the kind apt-get update; apt-get upgrade could fix on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Basile: thanks for taking the time to put some code around. It works the same way like mine: step through is fine, normal run crashes with the same error.

Comment: @Basile: it exists with no display.

Comment: @Paul: did sudo apt-get update but not much changed. Do I have to reboot the system? (Sorry, I'm using Linux for 3 months only).

Comment: @JustGreg It is generally helpful to reboot afterwards, though not always necessary.  Sometimes things break, like if something in a new kernel is incompatible.

Comment: @Basile: (addenda) Okay, I'll try to describe how I test my application:

1. Inside Eclipse, pressing Run button: not working, wxwidget failure
2. Inside Eclipse, entering debugger mode, step by step execution: working just fine

Bottom line: both inside Eclipse.